# D:/react-native tutorial/NavigationTut/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-navigation-tabs' in 'D:\react-native tutorial\NavigationTut'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

using react-navigation v4, this is my code I am facing this error, I have also checked the documentation

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
  import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
  import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
  import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
  import MyHomeScreen from './screen/Homescreen';
  import MyNotificationsScreen from './screen/Notification';

  const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: MyHomeScreen,
  Notifications: MyNotificationsScreen,
  });

 const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
 export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return <AppContainer />;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are connected with the same network, your system and mobile should be connected with the same wifi and also you have to upgrade your Expo CLI.